# Height of UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I calculate the height of a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` in `-tableview:heightForFooterInSection:`? I create the view ahead of time, and it contains dynamic text in the `textLabel` so has a varying height.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the other answers I used the following, I'm not entirely happy with this solution as it uses a hardcoded padding and it doesn't account for the `detailTextLabel`, but it works in my case.

```
- (CGFloat)heightOfHeaderFooterView:(UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view {
    return ceilf([view.textLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width - 2*self.tableView.separatorInset.left, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:view.textLabel.font} context:nil].size.height) + 20;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:) to calculate the height of your textLabel. Then you will be able to get the height of footer view.

If you change the text of your textLabel, remember to reload your tableView.

Another way:

```
textLabel.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, maxWidth, maxHeight);
[textLabel sizeToFit];
```

Then your textLabel's height will be correct.

Comment: As @Nick point out, it is better to do a ceilf() for the height value. We should use integer value for height although it support float value.

Answer (score 1):

As @Harrison Xi pointed out, you can use  `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`

```
CGRect headerFrame = [YOUR_STRING boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(240.f, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"" size:15.0f]} context:nil];

CGSize requiredSize = headerFrame.size;

return requiredSize.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of @Nick's answer in Swift 3:

```
func heightOfHeaderFooterView(view: UITableViewHeaderFooterView) -> CGFloat {
    if let text = view.textLabel?.text as NSString? {
        let size = CGSize(width: tableView.bounds.size.width - 2 * tableView.separatorInset.left, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let rect = text.boundingRect(with: size, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : (view.textLabel)!.font], context: nil)
        return rect.size.height + 20
    }
    return 0
}
```